# How to change the DropDownCheckboxes property SelectBoxCaption for multiple values in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

When user select multiple values from DropDownCheckboxes, and How can you show the selected values at the SelectBoxCaption.

How can i do it.

my .aspx code:

```
<%@ Register Namespace="Saplin.Controls" Assembly="DropDownCheckBoxes" TagPrefix="asp"%>
         <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="dropdown1" runat="server"   
         UseSelectAllNode="true" UseButtons="true"   
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged"     
         AutoPostBack="true"><Style DropDownBoxBoxWidth="200"/>
         </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
```

.cs

```
protected void dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
 List<String> checkedList = new List<string>();
 foreach (ListItem item in dropdown1.Items) 
{ 
if (item.Selected)
 {    
    checkedList.Add(item.Text);
 }
 }    
dropdown1.Texts.SelectBoxCaption = String.Join(",", checkedList);
}
```

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIiSE.png)

Can anyone help me

Thank you

Comment: selectbox caption means?

Comment: I would assume that you would have to use the OnSelectedIndexChanged event to update the SelectBoxCaption, though I  have no idea what it is, you should be able to get a reference to it in code and update it.

Comment: It is the one of the property for displaying all the selected items in dropdowncheckboxes. usage like this  `dropdown.Texts.SelectBoxCaption`

Comment: Hi, I updated my code. In that when check at compile time it displaying all selected items but at last result it will not the selected items properly when especially when i select large name.

Comment: i updated my image.